# Merge JSON files in Laravel 5.2 in a specific part of the main JSON

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to merge JSON files in Laravel 5.2 in a specific part of the main JSON.

**The case:**
I have one main config.json

```
{
  "layout": "normal",
  "modules": [
    "module1", "module2", "module3"
  ]
}
```

I have many module json files, which look like this (minimalised values for this question):

```
{
  "name": "module1",
  "description": "lorem ipsum"
}
```

**What I would like to achieve:** In the part, where "modules" is (module1, module2 etc.) I would like to load my other json files after eachother and save the file. Each of them as an object, so it would ideally look like:

```
{
  "layout": "normal", 
  "modules": [
    {
      "name": "module1",
      "description": "lorem ipsum"
    },
    {
      "name": "module2",
      "description": "lorem ipsum"
    }
}
```

All files are stored in ressources/assets/json and each json has the modulename as filename like this:

```
/json
   _module1.json
   _module2.json
   ....
```

**Question:** How can I achieve this in Laravel 5.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP doesn't offer a possibility to work on a JSON data directly. In order to add data to JSON in PHP you'll need to first decode it into an associative array, update the data and then encode into JSON again.

The following should do the trick:

```
// decode original JSON
$decodedData = json_decode($json, true);

// read and decode data for all listed modules into an array    
$moduleData = [];
foreach ($decodedData['modules'] as $module) {
  $moduleData[] = json_decode(file_get_contents("json/_$module.json"), true);
}

// add module data to the main array
$decodedData['modules'] = $moduleData;

// encode back into JSON
$json = json_encode($decodedData);
```